# increase width on overflow to adjust scrollbars

Tags: html, css

What should be my CSS to make a div adjust its width when scrollbar is visible.

Here is the scenario, I have a div and child elements

```
<div id="ListHolder"> 
     <ul id="LeftList">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
     </ul>

     <ul id="RightList">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

[image: example picture]

I want to adjust my div width automatically for scrollbars when it has overflow. Means when there is no scrollbar it should be like image on left side and when scrollbars becomes visible it should automatically adjust width for scrollbars. I do not want to use javascript but with pure CSS and HTML. And I believe it is possible with CSS and HTML only.

Considering above UL Lists, my CSS is something like

```
 #ListHolder
 {
     display:inline-block;
 }
 #ListHolder > ul
 {
     width:250px;     //<---Necessary to keep fixed width not percentage
     display:inline-block;
 }
 #ListHolder > ul > li
 {
     display:inline-block;
 }
 #LeftList
 {
     float:left;
 }
 #RightList
 {
     float:right;
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried till now. Will you please show fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: set `overflow: scroll` so you'll always have a scrollbar and it will remain consistent?

Comment: @BrianGlaz not I want the scroll to stay hidden and appear only when it overflows. The thing you say, scrollbar will always be there but inactive and activated when overflows.

Comment: Can you explain why it is necessary to have a fixed width on your ul elements?

Comment: because I have images just like above of fixed width

Comment: It is best practice for implementing responsive webdesign to use percentages or something like the flex layout when working with the web simply because of the plethora of screen sizes and resolutions available on the market. If you create a JsFiddle for your project then we can set you in the right direction.

Comment: I will make a JSFiddle for this but that would be just like the above

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow Great for the fiddle, I'm also keen on that but please use "float" instead of "flaot" in your CSS though

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow I think your best shot would be to make the scroll bar always visible even if there's no overflow, and get activated when there is an overflow, what do you think of this ?

Comment: @KarimAG I don't want it in that way or else there was no need to ask this. I just want it the way I said above.

Comment: Is this content loaded statically or is there a possibility of overflowing content getting loaded later, "long" after page is loaded (with this I mean if you add any content after page css is rendered)?

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow: which scrollbar are you talking about? If you want to apply the scrollbar on `#ListHolder` then you also need to set a fixed height.

Comment: @SalmanA I am talking about list holder scrollbar and I just want the scrollbar appear when it overflows otherwise stay like image on left side

Comment: @maremp Content will be added dynamically

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow is there any reason why you don't want to use JS? You'll need it for loading content so there is not a question of your page working on devices with disabled JS.

Comment: @maremp there is not a solid reason to not to use JS I wanted to do it without JS but pure CSS. But now this seems that I have to use JS.

Answer (score 13):

The content width of an element includes the width of scrollbar, and as far as I know, you cannot fight this behavior.

Suppose you are trying to create a shrink-wrap div that contains two 250px wide columns. The browser calculate its width as 500px, then the height, and if a scrollbar is required, it fits the scrollbar inside those 500px reducing the available width to 483px (or so).

A tricky solution is as follows:

- Add sufficient amount of right padding on the box that (could) display scrollbar
- Set `width` property on that box or make that box shrink-wrap around its contents
- Set `max-height` to desired value and `overflow-y` property to `auto` to trigger automatic scrollbar

At this point the box will be as wide as desired and the scrollbar, if visible, draws over the right padding; not interfering with the width.

In order to display the chrome (border and padding) you need to create additional divs.

- **`Demo` http://jsfiddle.net/salman/KZLmW/show/**
- **`Code` http://jsfiddle.net/salman/KZLmW/**

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div id="ListBorder">
    <div id="ListOverflow">
        <div id="ListHolder">
            <ul id="LeftList">
                <li></li><li></li><li></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="RightList">
                <li></li><li></li><li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (only the important bits)

```
#ListHolder ul {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}
#ListHolder {
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#ListOverflow {
    width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 350px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#ListBorder {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Note:

- `#ListHolder` is used for clear-fix
- `#ListBorder` can be used to add a border and padding to match the desired output

Comment: That's a nice trick. Thanks. I think this can be an alternate. I will award if no other better answer is provided.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you can reduce the padding on `#ListBorder` and `#ListOverflow` to get the result similar to the screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to increase the container's div when it overflows by pure CSS.

However, if you want to keep your actual layout (the flexbox model would be a better fit here, as @AlecMoore suggested), here's a workaround **for webkit only** : use the `overlay` value for `overflow`. It'll appear above your content, so it'll not slide down.

```
div{
    width: ...px;        /* Fixed width */
    overflow-y: overlay; /* Overlaying scrollbar for y axis */
}
```

[Here's a demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/Hq3gz/1)

Or, you could just adapt your div, make it slightly wider, so the scrollbar will fit in when needed ([demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Hq3gz/2/)).

Again, this is not the best solution ; if you aim to make something responsive, you should be using relative sizing units, and / or [flex-box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

*Note to unicorn lovers: I do love kittens, but **I prefer unicorns**. I'm using kittens, cause I miss an image placeholder website with cute unicorns... Please tell if you know one!*

Comment: Sorry but your fiddle just loses when it's overflow

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow Damn, I forgot that `overlay` is a webkit special value... Prefer the second solution for now

Answer (score 4):

As other people have mentioned, there is not way to adapt the width of the div based on the scrollbar condition only with CSS.

You could find a workaround like including the width of the scroll bar in your fixed width [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/XE3mx/13/). This is simple, effective, scollbar appears right of your content but it doesn't change the width of the container when the scrollbar appears.

CSS **can't set a conditional width** to the container based on scrollbar presence like :

1. if I have a scrollbar give me this width
2. if I don't have a scrollbar, give me this other width

So to achieve this exact behaviour you can't use CSS.

I wrote this simple JS (no library needed so it is lightweight) code that gives you the behaviour you are looking for :

```
var div= document.getElementById('ListHolder');
var hasVerticalScrollbar= div.scrollHeight>div.clientHeight;

if (hasVerticalScrollbar > 0) {
    div.style.width = '530px' ;
}
```

Now, this only works on page load. If you also want this behaviour when the window is resized, you can add :

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', function( event ) {
    var hasVerticalScrollbar= div.scrollHeight>div.clientHeight;
    if (hasVerticalScrollbar > 0) {
        div.style.width = '530px' ;
    }
    else{
        div.style.width = '500px' ;        
    }
}, false );
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/XE3mx/)**

*Note for unicorn lovers, I know april is nearly finished but there is a late easter egg for you in demos*

Comment: I think you are right there is no pure CSS trick for this and would have to go with Javascript. Let's see if someone answers before the bounty ends.

Comment: Look at my answer for a pure css solution.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adjusting the width depending of the visibility of the vertical scroll bar you can always reserve the width the scroll bar needs on the right side if it is visible.

```
padding-right: 2em;
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is actually pretty simple.

You need a wrapper element with `display: inline-block`. Then set the width of the child element.

```js
var count = 20;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML += '<p>another line</p>';
    if( --count === 0 )
    clearInterval(interval);
}, 250);
```

```css
/* important stuff */

#outer {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#inner {
  width: 300px;
}


/* styling */

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
}

#outer {
  padding: 20px;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  background: #ccc;
}

#inner {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

**http://jsfiddle.net/Z2WuJ/2/**

Giving the images or whatever content you're putting in there a max-width of 50% (for two columns) and setting the box-sizing to border-box you should get your desired result:

```
#ListHolder ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    max-width: 50%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly like you because I want to keep a fixed size not in percentage.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Z2WuJ/5/ . Using the wrapping container fixed width in combination with the percentage makes it able for you to easily keep a fixed width for the images..

Comment: Not dear I said I dont want to use percentage in width. I want to keep my width fixed eg: 200px not 50% or so.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the fixed width on the image? Why can't it be on the wrapping container? "400(wrapping container) * 0.50 = **200**"

Comment: Because when I tried it on my app it was not looking that good when images were scalled down

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make the div width taking in consideration the scrollbar width. Add a few pixels (30px) maybe to the div width. Then set the RighList and LeftList width to something like 49% each.

overflow-y:auto is causing your list to move because you are not taking the scrollbar width into consideration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not I already had that trick but that shows a bad impression when it's not overflow means 30px extra white space on right side

Answer (score 0):

I think your best shot would be to always display the scroll bar even when there is no overflow (the scroll bar would be deactivated and will get activated when the content of the page gets longer than the viewport).

You can achieve this using this code:

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; /* For FF */
    -ms-overflow-y: scroll; /* For IE */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* For others & old IE */
}
```

And here is a working **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KarimAG/z56wW/1/)**

Alternatively, if you are OK with setting a fixed width to your container div, you can ignore the width of the scroll bar by setting the overflow-y value to overlay which will make the content get behind the scroll bar on smaller viewports.

**Please Note: that `overflow:overlay;` is deprecated.**

Here you go:

```
html {
    overflow-y: overlay;
}
#ListHolder {
    display:inline-block;
    width:600px;              /* Fixed width */
}
```

And here is another **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KarimAG/z56wW/2/)**

Note that both approaches work correctly on modern AND older browsers such as the great IE8.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help but I had tried both ways before. But this is not the thing I seeks. Thanks anyway. I think there is no way doing this without Javascript I think.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could adjust your DIVs width to the presence of a scrollbar, I wouldn't recommend it. Consider that a user could have customized the size (width) of their scrollbars within their OS (Windows comes to mind).

Next, comes the fact that some browsers report the viewport's width **with** the scrollbar, while others report it **without**. Specifically, Chrome and Safari *exclude* the scrollbar dimensions, while Firefox, Opera and IE *include* the scrollbar dimensions.

I conclusion, I concur with the other answers that you should use `overflow: scroll`. Either that, or use javascript to use a custom scrollbar (which I think is overkill).

Reading material:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/rwd-scrollbars-is-chrome-better/
- http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201301/media_query_width_and_vertical_scrollbars/

Comment: Yes I think you are right. Let's see if someone comes from wood world to answer this before the bounty ends

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z56wW/3/)**

Just check the demo & inspect element and remove height from "#ListHolder" div you will see the width will adapt the change of scroll-bar presence.

If this is what you are looking for let me know and i will explain the logic behind it.

HTML:

```
<div class="overall-width">
    <div id="ListHolder">
        <ul id="LeftList">
            <li>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="RightList">
            <li>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
    /* For FF */
    -ms-overflow-y: scroll;
    /* For IE */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /* For others & old IE */
}
#ListHolder {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 610px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
#ListHolder > ul {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webki-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
}
#ListHolder > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
}
#LeftList {
    float:left;
}
#RightList {
    float:right;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
.overall-width{
    width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What it sounds like you want is `overflow:auto;` which will only show the scroll bar when the content needs to scroll. Otherwise it will hide the scroll bar.

So your div could look like this:

```
<div class="scroll"> 
    <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and your css:

```
.scroll {
    overflow-y:auto; /* Only scroll the y axis */
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the problem is that It will move second list to down.

Comment: Can you show me your css and html? If you have fixed widths on your ul elements, then you will run into some trouble. I would recommend percentages for your widths on our ul (if you don't have it already).

Comment: See I have added CSS into question

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could change the scrollbar. Something like this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background: #ccc
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background: #888
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #eee
}​
```

Also, you can find the IE css [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: well you have to define for each browser