# How to center scrollable content with header?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center some content. The content is larger than the parent and therefore requires scrolling. There is also a header at top. For some reason, the scroll height clips the scrollable content. Thoughts on how I should fix the issue?

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xgsqyu45/

```css
.app {
  height: 400px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain more precisely what you want to happen

Comment: It's in the description. "For some reason, the scroll height clips the scrollable content.". This is caused by `display:flex`. Centering the content is the issue.

Comment: So you mean the overlap between content scrolling and the main body. It is true?

Comment: That's right. Adding `display:flex` to center the content causes overlap between content and scroll container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items#values) says:

> **center**
> The flex items' margin boxes are centered within the line on the cross-axis. If the cross-size of an item is larger than the flex container, it will overflow equally in both directions.

The flex center is calculated using `height` 400px. So `align-items: center` is making the content overflow by 100px from top.

```
 100 = (600 - 400) / 2

here,
600 = content height
400 = .scroll and container height
```

Notice how the `.scroll` gets 500px [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) and not 600px. It's 100px less.

---

**Solution:**
We can transform the content if it is taller than the container using CSS [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) function. Assuming you want to keep shorter content at center we can use below solution. View it in 'full page' mode.

```css
:root {
  --app-height: 400px;
  --content-margin-top: 12px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app {
  height: var(--app-height);
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  
  transform: translateY(calc((max(100% + var(--content-margin-top), var(--app-height)) - var(--app-height)) / 2));
}


/* center lines for debugging */
.content::after {
  content: "-";
  color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 255);
  line-height: 3px;
}

.container::after {
  content: "-";
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(255, 0, 0);
  line-height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class=header></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="content">content1</div>
      <div class="content" style="height: 200px;">content2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Dashed lines mark the center for contents and container.

---

**Update 10th Feb 2022 :** *Simple solution* to cover the new requirements mentioned in comments.

 I think we are over complicating things. We just need `margin:auto` and `flex-shrink:0` to address all the issues:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app {
  height: 400px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  
   margin: auto;
   flex-shrink: 0;
}


/* center lines for debugging */
.content::after {
  content: "-";
  color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 255);
  line-height: 3px;
}

.container::after {
  content: "-";
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(255, 0, 0);
  line-height: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>1. Small content</div>
<div class="app">
  <div class=header></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="content" style="height: 100px; width:100px;">content1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>2. Taller content</div>
<div class="app">
  <div class=header></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="content" style="height: 600px; width:100px;">content1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>3. Wider content</div>
<div class="app">
  <div class=header></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="content" style="height: 100px; width:120vw;">content1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
<div>4. Taller and wider content</div>
<div class="app">
  <div class=header></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="content" style="height: 600px; width:120vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem ad perspiciatis earum atque dolorum laborum corrupti animi? Dolor, laudantium! Non cupiditate in eligendi modi temporibus at maiores iste tempora accusantium dolorem quibusdam magnam
        totam, rem voluptatum distinctio sapiente debitis praesentium unde esse corporis perferendis id amet autem. Reprehenderit, non molestias?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In case 3, note scrollbars shifts content a little bit due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23243840/15273968). User agents handle scrollbar widths differently.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer on the behavior of flex box. I see that the margin on `.content` is currently ignored. Do you know why? 

I also tried setting the width of `.content` to be larger than the parent width. It fails to scroll horizontally. Thoughts on a solution for this?

Comment: Only margin top was being ignored cos we need to consider it in transform calculations. I've updated the answer. There is no horizontal scroll because by default [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) is set to `1`. So the content are being shrunk. If you set `flex-shrink:0` then content will have actual set width and you'll start seeing the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @David I've added a new solution to the answer. Hope it covers everything.

Comment: Thanks for the solution with `flex-shrink: 0; margin: auto;` for the flex child. Have never even thought about such behavior of flex blocks.

Comment: This is the best answer for the following reasons:
1. Describes why content was clipped. Shows deep understanding of flexbox.
2. Test cases of all 4 scenarios (center, vertical scroll, horizontal scroll, and 2 way scroll).
3. Width and height dimensions are specified in CSS only once.
4. Meets all requirements including content padding/margin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution - replace the margin of your `.content` element to this:

```
.content {      
  margin:auto 12px;
}
```

Updated jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/odjnL09g/

Explanation: Essentially what is required is that `margin-top:auto` and `margin-bottom: auto` are set - this is explicit to children of flexbox elements. This keeps the element vertically centered when it's smaller than the parent container, but when it's larger it scrolls properly. If you need the 12px vertical spacing, you should place a child element inside `.content` and transfer any styling to that and add a `padding` property to the `.content`.

**Edit**: Updating the answer to reflect what the OP wanted, centering, both vertically *and* horizontally.

It required that the `.content` has `margin:auto` applied and remove the `justify-content:center` from the parent flexbox container to avoid a nasty clipping bug.

```
.scroll {
  // justify-content:center; // This is commented out to avoid clipping bug
}

.content {
  margin:auto;
}
```

Here is the fiddle to the final working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/c9foy54q/

Comment: What you described mostly works.  Horizontal scroll doesn't quite work when `content` width is larger than it's parents. Thoughts https://jsfiddle.net/b0cpagkz/2/

Comment: @David This is a completely different issue - my solution works as per your description for height. However, to answer this question as well, the problem is that `.content` is a flexbox element child, thus to specify its width, you must use the `flex` property - `flex:0 0 1000px` for your specific example. Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/s6k85vp7/  Regarding centering it for a larger parent, the same rules apply - aka, `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` required

Comment: Horizontal and vertical scroll was implied by the `  justify-content: center;  align-items: center;` properties on `.scroll`. In your solution, `.child` is clipped on the left side. Thoughts?

Comment: @David, when asking a specific question and expecting an answer you can't expect something based on what is implied. However, here is the solution to your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/c9foy54q/ Essentially, I removed the `justify-content:center` property of the parent container - the child element is centered on its own using the x-axis margins. :)

Comment: Very cool. It works. Thank you so much. Sorry about the miscommunication at the beginning.

Comment: @David no worries, glad that you found a solution to your problem - i think my solution was better than the selected one, since it doesn’t involve fixed dimensions and the second part came after than my answer but… what can you do? :)

Answer (score 0):

You are limiting the height of the `.content` element but you do not set `overflow:auto` or `overflow:scroll` on it - you only do on it's parent.

By the way, the `height:100%` on `.container` is problematic because the header already takes part of the parent's height. Better leave this height to be automatic.

**Demo:**
Here is the code in the question, with a long text added inside `.content', and below that the same code with little modifications in the CSS.

```css
.app {
  height: 400px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="content">
        Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.app {
  height: 400px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 12px;
  height: calc(100% - 24px);
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">.app
  <div class="header">.header
  </div>
  <div class="container">.container
    <div class="scroll">.scroll
      <div class="content">.content
        Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting `overflow:auto` on `.content` doesn't do anything. Content can be an image, or some opaque object.

Setting `height:100%` on `.container` is necessary to prevent the entire page from scrolling.

Thanks for the help but these suggestions are not helpful.

Comment: Hey, see the demo I added to the answer. Is that how you wanted it to look like?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is not what I wanted. `.content` should not be scrollable. `.content` can be an image. Consider it to be an opaque object that you can't put anything inside. The parent `.scroll` should scroll and always show `.content`. You can see that in my jsfiddle, that the scroll clips the top of `.content`.

Comment: Check again, `.content` is indeed not scrollable in my example, only `.scroll` (with the blue border) is. I now added labels. Anyway if you feel it's not in the direction the sure no problem and good luck :)

Comment: It's exactly what I'm trying to communicate. There should not be a scrollbar inside of `.content`. It should not scroll. Only the `.scroll` container should scroll and should make its child completely visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you set style for scrollbar see this code

```css
.auto {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 70px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.scroll {
  height: 70px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 17px;
}

.scroll div {
  border: 1px solid gold;
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


/* Track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Handle */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}


/* Handle on hover */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<p>scroll bar thakes up the whole div:</p>
<div class="auto">
  <div>
    a<br /> b
    <br /> c
    <br /> d
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<p>it should look like this :</p>
<div class="scroll">
  <div>
    a<br /> b
    <br /> c
    <br /> d
    <br />
  </div>
</div>

<p>but without this effect when there is no overflow:</p>
<div class="scroll">
  <div>
    a<br /> b
    <br /> c
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I provided the wrong jsfiddle link. The question description was correct but the link was wrong. Here's the correct one https://jsfiddle.net/xgsqyu45. Your thoughts is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Update. Content can be both higher and wider than container

The "intermediate flexbox" solution provides automatic switching between center and edge alignment of content, but only in one direction - either [horizontally](https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/VwzJdpz) or [vertically](https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/NWwdgWq). Therefore, I propose to choose which centering to keep and which to sacrifice.

For example, in this solution, the narrow content is centered and the wide content starts from the left edge of the container. In this case, the content will start from the top edge, regardless of its height. For clarity, I have included four examples with different content sizes in the code.

(The "vertical centered" solution is below in the first version of the answer.)

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/8yqxcm9e/

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.intermediate {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 12px;
  width: 150px;
}

.content.high {
  height: 600px;
}

.content.wide {
  width: 900px;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intermediate">
      <div class="content">Narrow content is centered horizontally</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="intermediate">
      <div class="content wide">Narrow content is centered horizontally</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="intermediate">
      <div class="content high">Wide content starts from the left edge</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="intermediate">
      <div class="content wide high">Wide content starts from the left edge</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 1st answer. Content can be higher but not wider than container

**I've understood the desired behavior like this:**

1. If the child box is small, it should be centered on the parent.
2. If the child box is large, then it should not be cut off at the top, but start from the top edge of the parent.
3. At the same time, the sizes of the blocks are not known in advance and their behavior must be adjusted to the sizes of each other.

**Problem:**

If we just use the `justify-content: center;` property, and the height of the child block is greater than the height of the parent, then the top part of the child block is cut off and not available for vertical scrolling.

**Solution:**

Use a hierarchy of three nested blocks too.
But make the outer container a flex block with a column direction, and give it the `overflow-y: scroll;` property.
And the intermediate block remains a flex block with the `justify-content: center;` and `flex-grow: 1;` properties.

```css
.container.scroll {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.intermediate {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center; 
}
```

So if the child block is smaller than the parent block, it is centered.
And if its height is greater than the parent's height, it starts from the parent's top edge.

**Notice:**

In the source code, the `.app` and `.header` blocks have a height in pixels, and `.container` has a height of `100%`. Thus, it goes beyond the `.app` block.

To prevent this, I've used flex-boxes for the entire layout too. I also changed the header's `height` property to `min-height` to prevent it from shrinking as the container grows.

**And here are demos for similar tasks:**

- [vertical scroll](https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/NWwdgWq)
- [horizontal scroll](https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/VwzJdpz)

```css
.app {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  min-height: 44px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
  
.container.scroll {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.intermediate {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.content.small {
  height: 250px;
}

.app + .app {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="container scroll">
    <div class="intermediate">
      <div class="content">Large content starts from the container's top edge</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="app">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="container scroll">
    <div class="intermediate">
      <div class="content small">Small content is centered</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution solved the vertical scroll issue. `content` is clipped on the left side when its width is larger than its parent. Thoughts on the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/a03q758m/

Comment: @David The "intermediate flexbox" solution provides automatic switching between center and edge alignment of content, but only in one direction - either horizontally or vertically. I've added the "horizontal" version to my answer

Comment: Your answer almost works. In the lower right hand quadrant, there is bottom margin.

Answer (score 0):

Just use display:grid instead of display:flex in .scroll class:

```css
.app {
  height: 400px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container {
  marign-top: 60px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vertical scroll works, but when I change the width of `content` to be larger than `container`, `content` gets clipped on the left side. What do you think is the issue?

Answer (score -1):

easily with set `align-items: flex-start;` on `.scroll` you can prevent that.

```css
.app {
  height: 400px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.content {
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background-image: url(https://yari-demos.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img/clock-demo-400px.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue with this solution is that content is not centered (vertically and horizontally) when it's smaller than the parent. It should also scroll in both directions when either width or height is larger than the parent.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `grid` on the `scroll` container to prevent the misalignment with the `header`, and `align-self: center;` to the `content` to align itself vertically inside the `container` and `justify-self` to align itself horizontally without being clipped. I've also changed `overflow` to `overflow: auto;` as you only need the vertical scrolling in your sample. I've included two snippets to show the behavior when the `content` is bigger than container and another one when `content` is smaller than smaller than `scroll`, both with the same code. See the snippets below:

Behavior when `content` is **bigger** than `scroll`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  height: 400px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Behavior when `content` is **smaller** than `scroll`(*same code*):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  height: 400px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 2000px;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `content` should always be centered (vertically and horizontally) when it's smaller than the parent. It should scroll in both directions when either width or height is larger than the parent.

Comment: I see if that's the case you can use `grid` on the  `scroll` class and give `align-self` to `content` class. That should align the `content` whether it's longer than the `scroll` container or smaller than it. Check the edited snippet above.

Comment: @David more on `align-self` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self).

Comment: added another snippet to show same behavior even if content is smaller than parent.

Comment: This solution doesn't scroll horizontally when `content` is larger than the parent without getting clipped.

Comment: Edited the snippet, changed the way the content by centering itself using `justify-self` rather than making the container center it. It now won't clip the content.